# Illegal access- this web application instance has been stopped already.

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7

I am getting following error , even after deleteing every thing from `webapps` folder and `catalina.out` file is automatically refreshing with this error.

I am using `tomcat7` and `java 1.7 open jdk`.

```
Aug 05, 2016 12:54:11 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1743)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1095)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor125.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

**What might be the problem?**

Comment: Errors in your code? Cosmic rays? This stack trace has very little useful information in it. Under what circumstances does this happen? Maybe removing your app completely is causing more problems than it fixes. **Have you tried turning the server off and on again?**

Comment: @tadman yes, after restarting tomcat7 , this problem resolved, but I want to know the reason of it for knowlege :-)

Comment: I have the same sort of odd problems with my JBoss deployments from time to time, random errors are thrown, but a restart does the trick. Not sure if there's a good explanation for why these things happen.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case, it was the library jar which I added to the lib directory of apache Tomcat.

This issue occurred when I referred to the classes from the jar in the lib directory. When I added the jar as a dependency on my war and removed it from the lib directory, it resolved my issue.

In your case, I think the MySQL driver jar that you must have added to the lib is causing this issue. Try adding it as a maven dependency or as a dependency from your resource directory and remove it from your lib directory of the tomcat. It should help with this issue.